# How could I format a python string from float number with fix length and width

Tags: python, string, format, precision

Provided my float number is `12.3456`, and I need it to be printed as `_12.34`, which means that the length of the number before `.` is 3 while the length after the `.` is still 2. I tried this `'{:.2f}'.format(12.3456)` which only give me `12.34` which shorts a space before number `1`. So how could I make my need possible ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the total width of the rendered string by putting a number before the period in the format string:

```
>>> '{:6.2f}'.format(12.3456)
' 12.35'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply an additional `.rjust(6)` (6 because 3 + 2 digits and a decimal point):

```
>>> '{:.2f}'.format(12.3456).rjust(6)
' 12.35'
```

Answer (score 1):

adding to @cody's answer, you can use `f` strings if you've python 3.6+

```
>>> f'{12.3456:6.2f}'
' 12.35'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about first converting the float to 2 decimal places then formatting it?
For example if you want to truncate it use math.floor, or use round() if you want to round or use the decimal module (import decimal) [python decimal module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)

Example code using math.floor:

```
import math
print('{0:_>6}'.format(math.floor(112.345*100)/100)) #112.34
print('{0:_>6}'.format(math.floor(12.345*100)/100))  #_12.34
```